# Protractor: How to expect browser url to equal url that have an id after registering new user?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, userid, jasmine2.0

I'm making some tests in Protractor and encountered a little problem:

I made a test to register a new user, when I finish registering it the url will be something like this:

```
#/user/592/profile
```

So, my question is, how can I manage to get the ID of the new user to get a true in my test? Something like this:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(browser.baseUrl+#/user/ID_OF_NEW_USER/profile);
```

How can I do this? If it's possible of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work for any number of digits in User id.

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
  var user_id=url.split("user/")[1].replace("/profile","");
  //it will return exactly user_id value
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl())
        .toEqual(browser.baseUrl+"#/user/"+user_id+"/profile");

});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works too! Can you explain me this line please? 
var user_id = url.split("user/")[1].replace("/profile","");

Comment: Let us assume your url is `www.example.com/#/user/592/profile`. url.split('user/') will split your url string with the delimiter as "user/" and the output will be an array ["www.example.com/#/","592/profile"]. Now we are taking the second value from the array and replacing the word `/profile` with empty value. thus the output will be `("592/profile").replace("/profile',") => 592`

Comment: Oh, now I understand, thanks a lot, it will be very useful for me in a future, I'll vote your answer as it works for all length of user_id and use less code lines :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: If i want to do the same thing but with the "user" part? In my app I have to two types of users, when you enter to your own profile the url says the type of user you are, something like this: "#/typeOne/user_id/profile", how can I do it?

Comment: You can use regex and replace all characters from the url. try the below code `var userId = url.split("#/')[1].replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')` the above code will replace all characters except numbers.

Comment: Now I want to take the user type, not the ID, how can I do that?

Comment: Ohh sorry for above answer. try the below code. `var userType = url.split("#/')[1].split("/")[0]`

Comment: It works :D Thanks a loooot! I wasn't familiar with split function, I've never used 'till now, Hope a lot of people will see this answers, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, User_Id will be generated dynamically. So you need to write some customized code to pick the new user_id and use it in expect condition. You can follow below code snippet:

```
 Code: 

     browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
      var startIndex=(url.indexOf("user/"))+5;
      var endIndex=(url.indexOf(startIndex))+2;
      var user_id=url.substr(startIndex,endIndex);
      //it will return exactly user_id value
      expect(browser.getCurrentUrl())
            .toEqual(browser.baseUrl+"#/user/"+user_id+"/profile");

    });
```

Comment: This throws me this error: 
- Failed: indexOf is not defined

Comment: I think it's almost working, now it throw this error: -Expected 'http://myapp.app/#/user/596/profile' to equal 'http://myapp.app/#/user/ser/596/profile/profile'. As you can see 'ser' and the last 'profile' shouldnt be there

Comment: we need to adjust the startIndex value.  I have updated to +4. Check it once

Comment: Well, I'm going to put how my code is right now:

browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
  var startIndex = (url.indexOf("paciente/"))+9;
  var endIndex = (url.lastIndexOf("/"))-1;
  var user_id = url.substr(startIndex,endIndex);
  //it will return exactly user_id value
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl())
    .toEqual(browser.baseUrl+"#/paciente/"+user_id+"/perfil");
  });

And receive this:

    ✗ should let register new paciente (4 secs)
      - Expected 'http://myapp.app/#/paciente/599/perfil' to equal 'http://myapp.app/#/paciente//599/perfil/perfil'.

Comment: @LuisPabloLopez, i have updated even lastIndex value and made +4 to +5 for startIndex as  well. plz have a look at once and update your code as well.

Comment: Now is working, my code is like this:

browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
  var startIndex = (url.indexOf("paciente/"))+9;
  var endIndex = (url.indexOf(startIndex))+4;
  var user_id = url.substr(startIndex,endIndex);
  //it will return exactly user_id value
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl())
    .toEqual(browser.baseUrl+"#/paciente/"+user_id+"/perfil");
  });


Thanks a lot :) And really sorry for extending the discussion with comments, I don't have enough reputation to start chats :) 
Thanks thanks thanks :D

Comment: Ur most Welcome @LuisPabloLopez. Happy to help people who are indeed of help

Comment: I have one more question that comes to my mind right now... What will happen if the user_id have only one digit, or two digits, or four, etc... ? This code I'm using right now will only work if user_id have three digits?

Comment: it will  work, if not you just need to update last index